# SORT dates that are not in same format - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table and I want to sort it by ascending order. Below command would work except not all of my dates are in correct format. Majority of them are in YYYY-MM-DD and few are in DD/MM/YYYY format. How would i sort them? Can i convert all of them in to on standard format and do the sorting?

**order by saledata desc**

| ID_NUMBER | SALEDATA | SALEAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-07 | 47,000 |
| 2 | 2020-03-25 | 51,470 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | 32,000 |
| 4 | 08/11/2019 | 21,000 |
| 5 | 2018-10-12 | 37,560 |

Comment: Converting to standard date format and sort is correct approach. Currently what is the datatype of `saledata`?

Comment: You should fix the fundamental problem -- you are storing dates as strings.  Fix your data model!

Comment: Currently it's stored as strings. It's an old DB so i will not be able to change the data model unfortunately

Comment: '08/11/2019' could be 11th August (North America, we love you) or 8th November (everywhere else in the entire world). Someone needs to have a word with the Americans.

Comment: Do not -- I repeat -- do not store dates in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use:

```
order by (case when saledata like '%/%/%'
               then to_date(saledata, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
               else to_date(saledata, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          end)
```

But you should fix the data model!  Don't store dates as strings.